# open edx android app installation

Tags: edx, openedx

i follow this steps for edx mobile

1.install edx fullstack on azure Ubuntu VM

2.after i change the following value in lms.env.json

"FEATURES" : {
    ...
    "ENABLE_MOBILE_REST_API": true,
    "ENABLE_OAUTH2_PROVIDER": true,
    "ENABLE_COMBINED_LOGIN_REGISTRATION": true
}

3.i create oauth2 from my edx admin panel
url : http://my azure vm name/api/mobile/v0.5/?app=android
redirect url : same as url
client type : public

4.clone edx-app-android in my windows machine.

5.using android studio i change the following values in my config file

API_HOST_URL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000' here i place my azure ip
OAUTH_CLIENT_ID: '' here i place my oauth id generate using step 3

​5.i enable port 8000 in my azure vm endpoints

when running the apllication in android studio it's show following error

org.edx.mobile.http.Api﹕ Auth response= {"error_description": "A secure connection is required.", "error": "invalid_request"}​

Answer (score 1):

Set `"OAUTH_ENFORCE_SECURE": false` in `apps/edx/conf/lms.env.json`.

Answer (score 0):

i overcome this use using ssl certificate. after SSL certificate it's work fine. because for oauth2 authentication ssl is required.